# Multiple platform configurations for single application

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, platform

I'm in the middle of designing solution in azure.
Could i use multiple platform configurations for one registered application?
**Is this a "good practice"?**

For example:

1. Web for dotnet backend
2. SPA for js frontend with MSAL2 implementation

All articles and tutorials use separate app registration but in this case what for MS provides "add a platform" feature :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add different redirect URLs with different platforms in the app registration, but it is not a good practice.
In your case, we always create two app registrations instead of mixing them together, one for frontend, one for backend, as you mentioned like the doc.